# Как построить диаграмму? Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import random

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5,5)),
               columns=['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'])
df1.plot(kind='bar')
```

На выходе получаю `AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)`, а не диаграммы

Comment: Это Jupyter или просто скрипт? Если Jupyter, можно попробовать магию %matplotlib inline.

Comment: нет, это просто скрипт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня ваш код работает без проблем

[image: У меня - работает]

Comment: где запускаете?

Comment: В IDE. У меня - Spyder

Comment: Я в python 3.7.1 Shell

Comment: Попробуйте в конец добавить plt.show(). И, естественно, импортировать как import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Добавил `import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt` и `plt.show()`  и Винде из командной строки все работает.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/433913)

Comment: @Vanyamba Electronics -  для ответа на вопрос надо 1) проверить, как работает код, в каких условиях срабатывает, в каких нет - это сделано. 2) дать рекомендации, что-бы код срабатывал и тогда, когда он ранее не срабатывал - это тоже сделано. Почему вы считаете, что это "Не является ответом на вопрос" и что по вашему таким ответом является. Вот то, что автор не подтвердил и не опроверг сделанную ему подсказку - с этим соглашусь. Но это уже вопрос к ТС.

Comment: спасибо, получилось